# UV map in cycles is different to eevee or textured view + apparently only one UV

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I bought a 3d model off an online store and I want to render it in cycles. In eevee and textured view its great, but as soon as I switch to cycles the UV completely changes and is all sorts of messed up. Its as if the projection of the UV is wrong. But when I go into the UV mapping mode, the faces are lining up where they are supposed to be.

What could be pushing the whole cycles texture to be 'off'?

I've looked up this issue and many people say its because there are two UVs or such, but I've looked and that doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm sure its something that's super obvious, but for all my searching I can't find a solution thus far. Much appreciated.

[image: Cycles render of the plane]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Delete that mapping node, and add a new link from the UV texture coordinate input to the bump image just to be safe. The mapping node is set for “point” which is probably messing things up, but since it is all zeroed there is no reason for the node to be there.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't have any effect.

Comment: could you please share a part of the object (a wing for example): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a debug, get rid of the UV nodes, plug the texture straight into Material Output[surface] - there will be no shading, but it will narrow if its a problem of a shader of a mesh/texure
You can try to change bmp to some modern format, try png. You can also try to resize it so its dimensions in pixels would be a power of 2, so: 512x512, 1024x1024 and so on.
if you have any modifiers on the model, also as debug you can try to collapse the stack

Comment: So get this! changed it from a .bmp texture to .png, and it worked! nothing else to change! 

Turns out that cycles doesn't like BMP textures :) Good to know and hopefully this will answer the question for someone in the future :)